# Существует ли библиотеки визуализации воспроизведения музыки на react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Существует ли библиотеки визуализации воспроизведения музыки на react

Answer (score 2):

Апишка JS, работающая с аудио, называется `AudioContext`. Соответственно, гуглим следующее

> react audiocontext visualization

По первой ссылке, можно найти [пример на гитхабе](https://github.com/elliehoward/react-audio-visualization), код будет примерно следующий:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.createVisualization = this.createVisualization.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createVisualization()
  }

  createVisualization() {
    let context = new AudioContext();
    let analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    let canvas = this.refs.analyzerCanvas;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let audio = this.refs.audio;
    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    let audioSrc = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    audioSrc.connect(analyser);
    audioSrc.connect(context.destination);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    function renderFrame() {
      let freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount)
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData)
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      console.log(freqData)
      ctx.fillStyle = '#9933ff';
      let bars = 100;
      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        let bar_x = i * 3;
        let bar_width = 2;
        let bar_height = -(freqData[i] / 2);
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height)
      }
    };
    renderFrame()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Sublime - 40oz to Freedom</h2>
        <div id="mp3_player">
          <div id="audio_box">
            <audio
              ref="audio"
              autoPlay={true}
              controls={true}
              src={"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/e4a8f30ca62b4d2a129cc4df76de66f43e12fa3f?cid=null"}
            >
            </audio>
          </div>
          <canvas
            ref="analyzerCanvas"
            id="analyzer"
          >
          </canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```